# How do can I add 2 miles to viewRegion.span.latitudeDelta?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

How do can I add 2 miles to viewRegion.span.latitudeDelta ? How do can I calculate kTwoMiles?

```
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion;
viewRegion.center = coordinateCentre;
viewRegion.span.latitudeDelta = latitudeMax - latitudeMin + kTwoMiles;  
viewRegion.span.longitudeDelta = longitudeMax - longitudeMin + kTwoMiles;

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: I liked this solution since it's very straight forward: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13611163/149231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to add 2 miles only in the latitudeDelta. Probably regionThatFits will resize longitudeDelta.

```
double kTwoMiles = (double)2/69; 
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion;
viewRegion.center = coordinateCentre;
viewRegion.span.latitudeDelta = latitudeMax - latitudeMin + kTwoMiles;  
viewRegion.span.longitudeDelta = longitudeMax - longitudeMin;

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is relatively complicated because every degree has a different delta.
At Earth's equator you will have 111 km per degree and at the poles 0 km. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length)