# Couldn't find UIscrollView as subview in mkmapview in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I am trying to get the UIScrollView in mkmapview. In iOS 5 my code is working fine but in iOS 6 app is crashing. I need scrollview to set the zoom level in mkmapview.

When I run my application in iOS5 it gives me scrollview, but in iOS 6 it returns MKSCrollContainerView

Here is my Code.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[[[mapView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[scroll setZoomScale:0.045551 animated:NO];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zoom in a MKMapView programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031787/zoom-in-a-mkmapview-programmatically)