# How to zoom in or out a MKMapView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I need my app to zoom in or out a `MKMapView`.

**Code**

I thought of animating the value of the `altitude` of a `MKMapCamera`. Though, this doesn't zoom in or out the map.

```
let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
    mapCamera.altitude = 1000000
    mapView.camera = mapCamera

    UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0., options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        mapCamera.altitude = 6000000
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
    })

    mapView.camera = mapCamera
```

**Question**

How do I zoom in or out a `MKMapView`? Are there any other ways to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zoom in a MKMapView programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031787/zoom-in-a-mkmapview-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks. There is no Swift code in these answers. Though, I am trying to convert it right now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension based on kevins answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129379/1488696

With it you'll be able to zoom in and out as required

```
extension MKMapView {

    // delta is the zoom factor
    // 2 will zoom out x2
    // .5 will zoom in by x2

    func setZoomByDelta(delta: Double, animated: Bool) {
        var _region = region;
        var _span = region.span;
        _span.latitudeDelta *= delta;
        _span.longitudeDelta *= delta;
        _region.span = _span;

        setRegion(_region, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Use it like so: `myMapView.setZoomByDelta(0.5, animated: true)`

MKMapCamera is used for 3D maps. So its likely not what you're looking for

Apple Docs

> An MKMapCamera object describes a virtual camera that you use to define the appearance of the map. A camera object creates a virtual viewpoint above the map surface and affects how the map renders its tiles and other content. You use a camera object to specify the location of the camera on the map, the compass heading that corresponds to the camera’s viewing direction, the pitch of the camera relative to the map perpendicular, and the camera’s altitude above the map. These factors let you create a map view that is not just flat but offers a more 3D-like experience."

Comment: Thank you! How do I call this extension? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I forgot it in first place. I got it working. I'm testing it right now. Thanks!

Comment: It effectively zooms in and out but it fails at keeping a certain location centered. Have you got any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: remove `;` symbols - they are extra in swift

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `setRegion:animated:`. It takes an MKCoordinateRegion parameter. The region includes a span, which determines the range of north-to-south latitude shown on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Does the `setRegion:animated: `method define the altitude? Please note I didn't downvote.

Comment: I haven't messed with altitude before. That was added to the map kit later and I haven't had occasion to use it yet.