# iOS MKMapView programmatically zoom via setRegion has bugs when UserTrackingMode is follow and map is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I try write programmatically zoom based on setRegion method

```
func zoomMap(byFactor delta: Double) {
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion = self.mapView.region
    var span: MKCoordinateSpan = mapView.region.span
    span.latitudeDelta *= delta
    span.longitudeDelta *= delta
    region.span = span
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

I find two problems with it.

**First problem**

- when map is rotated, `setRegion` return map to north

I resolve it via `camera.altitude` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44025008/4554314)

**Second problem**

- when mapView `userTrackingMode` property is `follow` and I programmatically zoom it after some seconds map returns its zooming state in default `follow` zooming. Approach "disable userTrackingMode -> zoom -> enable userTrackingMode" does not help.

When I zoom map via UI gesture `userTrackingMode.follow` works normally. Is it iOS MKMapView bug?

Tested in iOS 10.

Comment: Second one: have you tried to disable userTrackingMode -> zoom -> enable userTrackingMode?

Comment: @mcgtrt does not help